# How to set up URL of ASP.NET Core Web Application in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express

I've create a ASP.NET Core Web Application in Visual Studio 2015 named "HelloASPNETCore", with the default template which has one controller "Home" and several actions "Index", "Contact".....etc; now I want to launch it on IIS Express with the root URL as

```
http://localhost:29492/HelloASPNETCore
```

but the default URL that Visual Studio set up to me is

```
http://localhost:29492
```

In the classic ASP.NET MVC Web Application Project I just specified the Project URL in the Project Properties and it works, but it's not work on the ASP.NET Core Web Application Project. I input the URL http://localhost:29492/Home/Index on browser and got the correct content respond, but http://localhost:29492/HelloASPNETCore/Home/Index gave me the empty content, without any error information.

Answer (score 21):

In the *properties* folder you have the file *launchSettings.json*, where you can set some settings of your application.

You will find something like this :

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52023/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "index",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "YOUR_PROJECT_NAMESPACE": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:52023/index",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've found the launchSettings.json and modified it as

Comment: Sorry I've not finished my previous comment.
I've modified the  launchSettings.json then re-launch but still got empty content from http://localhost:29492/HelloASPNETCore. Due to the content length limitation I can't post my launchSettings.json content here.

Comment: If you have empty content it's note a launch configuration problem. You may have a routing problem, or a controller's action rendering empty content.

Comment: In addition to modify launchSettings.json, do I have to modify the routes.MapRoute code on the Startup.cs as well?

Answer (score 7):

You can define it where you are writing server related stuff like

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseUrls("http://localhost:29492/HelloASPNETCore")
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

If you are using visual studio then you can do it by modifying `properties/launchSettings.json` file with the correct `launchUrl` like this:

```
"launchUrl": "http://localhost:29492/HelloASPNETCore"
```

For more details follow this [article](http://benfoster.io/blog/how-to-configure-kestrel-urls-in-aspnet-core-rc2)

You have to setup the routing to support.